# DataTable.Delete() Removing rows before Accept Changes

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I'm having an issue where I mark several rows for deletion within a loop, but when it gets to a certain point in the loop, the rows actually start to be removed.

As you can see what I'm basically doing is checking if the row needs to be deleted and if so, add it to a new table and delete it.

The problem is this works for the first 60 ish rows, then all of a sudden the rows appear to actually be removed and it eventually throws a row with that index doesn't exist error (at 65).

The original table is a list of contacts with firstname, lastname, email and company, with 70 records.

I tried to cut the list in half, but then the issue started happening at around row 23.

```
            dtSelectCompany = dt_data.Clone
            Dim s_company As String
            Dim b_add As Boolean
            Dim dtCompanies As Data.DataTable

            For i = 0 To dt_data.Rows.Count - 1

                b_add = False

                s_company = dt_data.Rows(i).Item(columnsDictionary("company")).ToString

                If s_company = "" Then : b_add = True
                Else
                    dtCompanies = crm_functions.getCompaniesByName(s_company.Replace(" ", "%"))
                    If dtCompanies.Rows.Count > 1 Then : b_add = True
                    ElseIf dtCompanies.Rows.Count = 1 Then
                        dt_data.Rows(i).Item(columnsDictionary("company")) = dtCompanies.Rows(0).Item("id")
                    Else : b_add = True
                    End If

                End If

                If b_add Then
                    Dim temp_row As Data.DataRow = dtSelectCompany.NewRow
                    temp_row.ItemArray = dt_data.Rows(i).ItemArray.Clone()
                    temp_row.Item("fullName") = temp_row.Item(columnsDictionary("firstname")) & " " & temp_row.Item(columnsDictionary("lastname"))
                    dtSelectCompany.Rows.Add(temp_row)
                    dt_data.Rows(i).Delete()
                End If

            Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a counter, use a datarow, for example:

```
dtSelectCompany = dt_data.Clone
Dim s_company As String
Dim b_add As Boolean
Dim dtCompanies As Data.DataTable
Dim MyDataRow as DataRow
For Each MyDataRow IN dt_data.Rows
            b_add = False

            s_company = MyDataRow("company").ToString

            If s_company = "" Then : b_add = True
            Else
                ' not sure what crm_functions is, so left this alone
                dtCompanies = crm_functions.getCompaniesByName(s_company.Replace(" ", "%"))
                If dtCompanies.Rows.Count > 1 Then : b_add = True
                ElseIf dtCompanies.Rows.Count = 1 Then
                    MyDataRow("company")) = dtCompanies.Rows(0).Item("id")
                Else : b_add = True
                End If

            End If

            If b_add Then
                Dim temp_row As Data.DataRow = dtSelectCompany.NewRow
                temp_row = MyDataRow
                temp_row.Item("fullName") = temp_row.Item(columnsDictionary("firstname")) & " " & temp_row.Item(columnsDictionary("lastname"))
                dtSelectCompany.Rows.Add(temp_row)
                MyDataRow.Delete()
            End If
Next
```

Wrote this off the top of my head, so .....

Comment: I have since resolved the issue which was to do with editing the datatable before the above and not accepting the change - I didn't realise you needed to accept changes after adding rows.